# how to extract multiple zipped and rar files recursively?

Tags: tar, zip, extract, unzip

I have a folder `ExampleFolder` which contains many zipped folders. These zipped folders also contains multiple zipped folders. How to go through `ExampleFolder` and extract all of its zipped folders recursively?

Note that `ExampleFolder` itself, is not zipped, it's just a normal folder

Okay now I know what's happening Rinzwind and nux answers are both correct (except that I have to keep pressing Y or A forever)

But it's seems that some of the zipped files, contained zipped files and rar files as well, the rar files will not be extracted by

```
while [ "`find . -type f -name '*.zip' | wc -l`" -gt 0 ]; do find -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -- '{}' \; -exec rm -- '{}' \;; done
```

or whatever

**Edit 2** Some files are named `.r00` and `r01`, .`r02` up to r14, they are `rar` files, but not `.rar`

Comment: This isn't going to be a simple terminal command but a complete shell script, so yes it's programming. Take a look at the manual page of [`unzip(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) for a start.

Comment: @fisher just wondering... would `unzip 'ExampleFolder/*.zip' && unzip 'ExampleFolder/*/*.zip'`  not do what you want? (at least 2 levels but you do not seem to need more ;) ) (these single quotes need to be backticks :P )

Comment: @Rinzwind none work, they keep asking if I want to rename or replace, i have to keep pressing `y`and they don't extract, I don't know what they actually do, but the fact that I have to keep pressing y forever is depressing :P

Comment: @Fischer check the code in my answer and reply

Comment: pressing y means that some of them contains file with same name , y for confirmation to overwrite

Comment: @nux I updated my question

Comment: @Rinzwind I updated my question

Comment: @Fischer i try it on 2 level zip files and it worked fine , do they contain the same data ?

Comment: @nux I do not know what data they contain, 800mb of zipped files, I can't go through all of them, maybe a file is zipped 5 times i don't know

Comment: why you dont make a test , copy 10 files to a new directory , and try my code

Comment: @nux I did, they extracted the zip files, not the rar files, I edited my question to explain what's happening

Comment: add .rar after .zip

Comment: @nux it gives `paths must precede expression: .rar` something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command , it will recursively unzip all files in your current directory .

**Note** This will delete original zipped files , but If you want to leave original files , delete `-exec rm -- '{}' \;` code .

**Command :**

```
while [ "`find . -type f -name '*.zip' | wc -l`" -gt 0 ]; do find -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -- '{}' \; -exec rm -- '{}' \;; done
```

Comment: this code didn't extract everything but I solved the issue by using another version of the software which isn't zipped so issue solved

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can imagine is to extract the zip, then extract what was inside.

Say, in `ExampleFolder` you had `Example-A.zip`. Just extract the `.zip`s out of `Example-A.zip` (presumably into a folder named `Example-A-Folder`), then extract each of them one-by-one. This can be troublesome in cases where compressing it recursively (on Windows, something like `Example.zip.zip.zip` would crop up) leads to a compressed folder inside another inside another, etc.